# can you bind 2 way communication to a redux variable?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux

Forgive the newbish nature of this question.  Just learning react native and redux with react native

I have a redux store built and running in a react native app.  I can store and get values and such, but i have a question.

Say i have a img filename string value for save profile avatar.  I bind it to an avatar source and say in the update profile screen I update my avatar, save it to the database as well as update it redux value which is where the avatar source is getting the file name.  Is there a way or methodology that i can use so that when the redux value changes, the avatar change as well to reflect the update.

Again, im very new to react and react native as a whole, and this may just be easy to accomplish, im just learning.

Thanks

Comment: whenever your redux state is changed, it will automatically update your component.

Comment: Is there a reason to jump straight into redux? Have you determined that your app needs a store? It is best to learn React first before adding the nightmare of redux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only update your redux store with the help of Redux actions and reducers.
To get access to the redux store in any of your component, you need to connect to redux store using High order component `connect`
Your component will update once your component state or props are changed.
So to update your avatar inside your component you must be passing it as a prop.
If you are doing these things correctly then after updating your redux store your component will definitely be receiving updated props.

Let me give you one example -

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  user: state.user,
  data: state.data
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Post);
```

In the above example, `mapStateToProps` is used to map data inside the store to the local component as props.
So in above example whenever `user` and `data` are updated in the redux store, it will be going to update the `post` component with updated values of user and data.
Note here is that you can pass these props to as many components as you want and all will get updated values through props once store is updated.

Reference -
https://react-redux.js.org/api/connect
https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/connect-mapdispatch